# Creating common data model for greenDao and retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit, greendao

I have json reponse from a web service  which is like this

```
{
 "id":1,
 "name":"abc",
 "address": {
               "streetName":"cde",
               "city":NY
            }
}
```

I am using Retrofit and greenDao for my project . For both we  need a data model . For retrofit only , my data model look like this

```
public class Example {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Address address;

    public Example() {
    }

    public Example(Integer id, String name, Address address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }


    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}




public class Address {

    private String streetName;
    private String city;

    public Address() {
    }

    public Address(String streetName, String city) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
        this.city = city;
    }


    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }


    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }


    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

}
```

Which can be used for `Retrofit` , but `greenDao` has a generator , which also make data model . How can I generate Datamodel from greenDao generator project , which can be used for both retrofit and greenDao

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how a generator should look like:

```
    Schema schema = new Schema(1, <your.package.id.where.models.are.held>);

    Entity model = schema.addEntity("Model");
    model.addIdProperty();
    model.addStringProperty("name");

    Entity address = schema.addEntity("Address");
    Property addressIdProperty = address.addIdProperty().getProperty();
    address.addStringProperty("streetName");
    address.addStringProperty("city");

    model.addToOne(address, addressIdProperty).setName("address");

    DaoGenerator generator = new DaoGenerator();
    generator.generateAll(schema, "./app/src/main/java");
```

As you can see, the `Model` class contains a reference to address, by adding one-to-one relation and naming it "address".

This way any json parser like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) can parse your objects and put them in database.